# Extract specific information in a log file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, logging, cron

shell.log and log format is like below,

```
I, [2018-03-07T10:21:26.315447 #7531]  INFO -- : POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v3/internal/allowed 6.69490
I, [2018-03-07T10:21:26.315799 #7531]  INFO -- : gitlab-shell: executing git command <git-upload-pack /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GitLab-write-logs/write-logs.git> for user with key key-1.
I, [2018-03-07T10:23:00.567841 #7739]  INFO -- : POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v3/internal/allowed 5.55714
I, [2018-03-07T10:23:00.568227 #7739]  INFO -- : gitlab-shell: executing git command <git-upload-pack /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GitLab-write-logs/write-logs.git> for user with key key-1.
I, [2018-03-07T10:23:49.932948 #7851]  INFO -- : gitlab-shell: executing git command <git-receive-pack /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GitLab-write-logs/write-logs.git> for user with key key-1.
I, [2018-03-07T10:55:29.533385 #4778]  INFO -- : gitlab-shell: executing git command <git-receive-pack /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GitLab-write-logs/write-logs.git> for user with key key-1.
I, [2018-03-07T10:55:29.810478 #4790]  INFO -- : POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v3/internal/allowed 0.10971
```

If you see the above log file details, you can see this quoted pattern in some of lines

" < git-upload-pack /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GitLab-write-logs/write-logs.git> for user with key key-1."

This means **git-upload-pack** is an activity which is happening on directory " **/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GitLab-write-logs/write-logs.git**" by user with ssh key **"key-1"**

Now I want to track this specific "git-upload-pack" activity on different directories whenever it is recorded in shell.log file

I am looking to write a script and with help of cron job to keep reading the new lines with this specific activity. I would the script to do below activity.

I am considering here, second line from top in log file with number #7531

Here now I see "git-upload-pack" string in the second line, so script should extract the directory information from the line which is "/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GitLab-write-logs/write-logs" and create a directory name at different path location and there create a log file inside the newly created directory and echo "$key-1 $Time stamp" >> to that log file.

Shell.log file keep updates as the activities happens everytime, Script should capture the details once it shouldn't capture same activity. How can I achieve this output?

Thank you All

Comment: There's no `git-upload-` in the samples. Please, read [how to ask useful questions aka MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, the string is there :p . Try to improve your question anyway.

Comment: I have edited the question, can you guys please look now

Comment: It's a broad question and you haven't provided some code effort of your own which is required for a MCVE. Here are some hints anyway: this line will extract the info you need from the log `sed -rn '/git-upload-pack/ s/^I, [[]([^ ]+) .*[]] .* with key ([^\.]+).$/\2 \1/p' some.log`. You need also code to read a file at intervals keeping track of the last line read, not a trivial task. Try to write your code and update the question.

Comment: Hi, in the provided shell.log file .                                                                           How can I extract '/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GitLab-write-logs/write-logs' when git-upload- matches...It should consider the line which matched string ..there are other lines also but it should consider each line individually when string matched